# Bottom-always (non-sticky) footer working with different window sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a footer which always be on the bottom of the page BUT isn't sticky. It's demand It'll be responsive. At the moment it's only on the bottom in two cases: first when I set bottom property to -350px (giving bottom:0px causing my footer lands somewhere in the middle of the page) or second when I manually change it's window size (as you probably notice I'm using Bootstrap). 
Because I want to set a dynamic gallery in the future (when you scroll down the
 more images will be appearing) I've tried to cope with this using JQuery but ... it seems to have some bugs I can't see. What should I do ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var currentHeight = $(document).height();
  /*alert(currentHeight);*/

  var currentFooter = currentHeight - 50;

  $('footer').css("bottom", currentFooter);

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    /*var navHeight = $(window ).height() - 67;*/

    var heHeight = $('.header').height();

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > heHeight) {
      $('nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  top: -75px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(222, 213, 213, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(222, 213, 213, 0.75);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(222, 213, 213, 0.75);
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

section {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

nav h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 39px;
}

nav p {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav p .yours {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

section ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 9px;
}

section ul li a {
  color: rgb(132, 132, 132);
  text-decoration: none;
}

section li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/*#lorem{
      
      width:640px;
      height:500vh;
      font-size:14px;
      padding-top:50px;
      margin:0 auto 0;
    }
    */

.bg-grey {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

#their {
  display: block;
  /* padding-left: 10px;
        margin-left:40px;
        padding-right:500px;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
        padding-top:5px;
        padding-bottom:5px;*/
  width: 342px;
  height: 15px;
  background: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 22px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#th p {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#th p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.thumbnail {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: rgb(85, 102, 119);
  !important
}

#own {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  padding: 20px 102px;
  margin-right: -190px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#own:hover {
  /*background:rgba(255, 196, 0, 0.18); */
  background: rgba(244, 97, 19, 0.72);
  color: black;
}

#th {
  /*
       display: block;
       position:relative;
       
        top:-70px;
        padding-top:20px;
        right:-10px;
        width:500px;
       
        height: 2000px;
     */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 330px;
  left: 810px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#th input {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  /*bottom:-350px;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>

<nav>
  <h2>TRAVEL MOOD</h2>
  <p><span class="yours">what</span> is <span class="yours">your's ?</span></p>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid all">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <p class="to_know">GET TO KNOW THEIR STORIES</p>
      <div id="their"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid  bg-grey" id="portfolio">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="china.jpeg" alt="china" class="img-responsive">
          <p>Donald & Ronald</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="tatry.jpeg" alt="tatry" class="img-responsive">
          <p>Louis</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="vienna.jpeg" alt="vienna" class="img-responsive">
          <p>Alejandra</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="croatia.jpeg" alt="croatia" class="img-responsive">
          <p>Marlene & Rita</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="almostcolorado.jpeg" alt="almostcolorado" class="img-responsive">
          <p>X & Y </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="country.jpeg" alt="county" class="img-responsive">
          <p>Mr Doe & Mrs Doe</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form id="th">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm active" id="own">CREATE YOUR OWN !</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>WEATHER</p><br>
      <input type="radio" name="weather" value="no_matter" checked> no matter<br>
      <input type="radio" name="weather" value="warmer"> warmer<br>
      <input type="radio" name="weather" value="colder"> colder<br>
      <input type="radio" name="weather" value="the_same"> the same<br>
      <p>COMPANY</p><br>
      <input type="radio" name="company" value="some_time_alone" checked> no matter<br>
      <input type="radio" name="company" value="couple"> couple<br>
      <input type="radio" name="company" value="with_family"> with family<br>
      <input type="radio" name="company" value="girls_boys_adventure"> girls/boys adventure<br>
      <p>HOW FAR</p><br>
      <input type="radio" name="location" value="another city" checked> another city<br>
      <input type="radio" name="location" value="another country"> another country<br>
      <input type="radio" name="location" value="another continent"> another continent<br>
      <p>PLACE WHERE YOU CAN</p><br>
      <input type="radio" name="activity" value="active"> stay active<br>
      <input type="radio" name="activity" value="leisure"> have some leisure time<br>
      <input type="radio" name="activity" value="party"> part..y/cipate<br>
      <input type="radio" name="activity" value="culture"> bite some culture<br>
    </form>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: can you clarify : 1)at bottom not sticky. Do you mean at bottom window or lower if enough contents to push it down off the screen ? 2)do you use bootstrap-3 or 4 ?

Comment: @G-Cyr Hi! 1) I want it to be visible when you scroll down to the bottom of the page - not always visible as my navbar for example. 2) I'm using Bootstrap4.